# How can you use a new toolbox in an older version of MATLAB? (no permissions to the older MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, directory, directory-structure

I'd like to use a function from MATLAB 2013b that does not exist in the version of MATLAB I need to use (on a cluster). I've tried re-implementing the function several different ways, but there are lots of dependencies, and when I seem to get passed these MATLAB crashes with a very long error message including this:

```
This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files
```

Unfortunately I know very little about C/MEX files.

Since I have MATLAB 2013b on my computer, I tried transferring the entire toolbox to the working directory on the cluster. This makes no difference if the toolbox is not expanded. When i put the most relevant files directly in the directory (rather than the subdirectories of the toolbox) I still get the same error as above.

Firstly, I am wondering if there is a neater way to make this toolbox override the original toolbox, rather than putting all subdirectories and .m files directly in the working directory.
Secondly, if I do override the old toolbox in this way, will this even work, or does MATLAB have some sort of block on using updated toolboxes in older versions?

Comment: Using new software on old stuff RARELY works.

Comment: How old is the previous version?

Comment: It's only 2013a, the version before

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB doesn't guarantee backward compatibility.  It's not just the functions in the toolbox - the toolbox functions might also be making assumptions about the required input or output of some non-toolbox functions which no longer apply.

However, if you're only moving only one version back, it might not be insurmountable with some tweaking.

1. Put your new toolbox in it's own directory, make sure it is on the path.
2. Rename/move/take off path the old version of the toolbox, so that
   you're sure none of those are getting called.
3. Check the 2013b [release notes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/release-notes.html), particularly for anything marked
   with a little warning triangle - that means "Compatibility
   Considerations".  There are separate release notes for the toolboxes as well.
4. If possible, and you didn't recompile when originally shifting the new toolbox to the cluster, recompile any MEX files belonging to the toolbox.

Without knowing which function/toolbox you're looking at, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Great, thank you very much, will give this a go. Sorry for not being more specific... I would like to use the crossentropy function from the nnet toolbox, which 2013a doesn't have.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do "2" because i don't have access permissions to the old version of MATLAB.